# Validate functions returning false all the time in vb.net winform project

Tags: regex, vb.net, winforms, validation

I have a form that takes in a persons details which include contact number and email and saves it to a database. I have 2 validate functions (regex expressions) that ensure that the contact number and email are in the correct format, this works fine. I have a second form that displays the persons details, this also works fine. The problem is when I go to edit the persons details on the second form. The validate functions return false when the update button is clicked even though they should return true. They are the exact same functions in the second form as in the first form, in fact the 'If' statements calling the functions are identical. I have attached the code for the 'If' statement and functions. Can anyone help with this problem?

So Just to be clear, the validate functions work fine in the first form but return false in the second form all the time, even when they should return true.

```
If Not validatePhone(txtContactNumber.Text) Or Not validateEmail(txtEmail.Text) Then
.....
EndIf

'Validate contact number.
Public Function validatePhone(ByVal strContactNum As String) As Boolean 'validate contactNumber
    Dim numberPattern As String = "^\d{1,5}-\d{4,10}$" 'Regex expression pattern
    Dim rxPhone As New Regex(numberPattern) 'Regex Object
    Dim phoneValid As Boolean 'If true contact number is valid

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strContactNum) Then
        phoneValid = rxPhone.IsMatch(strContactNum) 'Check validity
    Else
        phoneValid = False 'Not valid contact number or txtContactNumber is empty
    End If
    Return phoneValid
End Function

'Validate email.
Public Function validateEmail(ByVal strEmail As String) As Boolean 'validate email
    Dim emailPattern As String = "^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$" 'Regex expression pattern

    Dim rxEmail As New Regex(emailPattern) 'Regex Object
    Dim emailValid As Boolean 'If true email is valid

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strEmail) Then
        emailValid = rxEmail.IsMatch(strEmail) 'Check validity
    Else
        emailValid = False 'Not valid email or txtEmail is empty
    End If
    Return emailValid
End Function
```

Comment: Set breakpoints in debugger and check values that you pass to the validation functions in the second form.

Comment: It's better to move these functions to a common class. Don't copy the same code between forms.

Comment: I have debugged them and for some reason it's going to false the whole time. I will try your second suggestion now.

Comment: I assume that functions work fine, but receive bad values. Add MsgBox.Show(strContactNum) as the first line in validatePhone for example.

Comment: If the functions are same, the only thing would be the input. Perhaps your input contains some white space character?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the input, the email or contact number could be the exact same as when they were first put into the database in the first form. There is nothing wrong with the values it's getting either, strContactNum holds the correct value.

Comment: My apologies, there is white spaces at the end of both the email address and phone number. It seams to be coming from the database, I have each field in the database set to a certain length, e.g. 150 for email, so if there's 20 characters in the email address, there are 130 white spaces. Is there a way of preventing this or should I ask a new question?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question for the database stuff.  But out of interest... which DB is it?  I work with SQL, SQL CE and Access and usually setting a String/NVarChar to a certain length doesn't return a load of trailing spaces.

Comment: Just use `TRIM()` when passing it through to your validation function...

Comment: Show us the definitions of the email and phone number columns in the database.

Comment: Thanks guys, changing the datatype from char() to varchar() solved that problem. There are no white spaces after the email or contact number and the validate functions are working fine.